# Selenium Webdriver automation with emails

Tags: c#, email, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently trying to use Selenium Webdriver (C#) to automate a Forgot Password -> Reset Password workflow, where the user navigates to a page and supplies their username, and the backend code validates the username, then sends an email with a reset password link to the email address associated with their account.

I'm able to automate the process up to the point where the code sends the email, but I don't know any ways of checking for the email and/or clicking a link in the email, so I was hoping someone more experienced with Selenium/automation may be able to give me a few pointers.

Ideally the test should not care about the email address that the email is being sent to. Is there a way for Selenium WebDriver or some 3rd party package to catch the email being sent?

Thanks for any input or suggestions.

Comment: What is this test supposed to prove? The application can only send an email to someone, it cannot ensure that email is *actually* received by the user. Ergo, your test cannot either.

Comment: Just wanted an end to end test verifying that a user can click forgot password and reset their password with the link provided in the email.   I can see your point though, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a way around that would be to dump the email locally or to some storage. For instance, modify the application so that it dumps the email to a database or a local file and **then** sends the email? You can then take the email before the SMTP client in .NET sends it off. This would then save the unnecessary SMTP querying in your current solution (that you mentioned in the comment to the answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You are talking about setting up an email server, which is not an easy task.

You should send it to a test work email (if this is for a company), or a public email (hotmail/gmail), or if security is not an issue at all, the easiest place to send it would be a disposable email (mailinator)

Comment: I was hoping to use some magic catch all outgoing email "net" to simplify and avoid the necessity of querying mailboxes using a 3rd party nuget package. I went with the test work email route  and querying it with MailSystem.Net. Works well enough. Thanks for the info.

Comment: You can actually setup a simple desktop email server for use in testing. There are several available, an example is [papercut](http://papercut.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @Faiz That's pretty awesome.  I looked at the webpage...if an application on a different computer attempts to send an email to it, do you send it to an IP address?

Comment: @NathanMerrill - that should work. Set the IP address to the machine IP address in Options; haven't tried it though. You can alternatively use something like hMailServer for a more permanent solution.

Comment: If you don't want to set up your own email server, want to keep things private and allow for automated testing, then check out http://mailosaur.com
Disclaimer: I'm the co-founder.

Comment: @NathanMerrill regarding to disposable email tools, have a look at [PutsBox](http://putsbox.com), it's a combination of disposable email tools with HTTP request recorders. This [post tutorial](http://www.pablocantero.com/blog/2015/08/05/test-emails-with-automated-testing-tools/), gives some usage examples.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [PutsBox](http://putsbox.com). You can send an email to whatever-you-want@putsbox.com, wait for a few seconds (SMTP stuff ins't instantaneous) then check your email via http://preview.putsbox.com/p/whatever-you-want/last.

Have a look at this [post tutorial](http://www.pablocantero.com/blog/2015/08/05/test-emails-with-automated-testing-tools/), it can give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

There is no integration of selenium with email clients like Thunderbird/Outlook. But if you have a web interface of the same email client, then you can access the email from browser and using selenium you can read and respond to the emails. I have tried this recently and it works fine where I have used web Outlook for testing.
Hope this helps.

Comment: While this definitely works, you become dependent on the mail application's interface. If they update and change the interface you'll have to update your test for change you didn't introduce. It's worth looking at though.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was in a similar situation and was able to successfully implement a way to get an activation or forgotten password links.

Using Java Mail API  I was able to trigger a method when such action is performed which goes into a Folder and read a specific message line then get the link and open it up in a browser using WebDriver.

However the main drawback with this is the inconsistency of reading a specific folder, sometimes emails goes to spam or other folder (in case of Gmail the new Social Folder) making it invisible or difficult to be retrieved.

Overall i think its a process that shouldn't really be automated, In terms of testing it should be done more code base level by mocking responses.
Snippet below should give you an idea on how to go about implementing

```
public class RefactoredMail {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore();
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "username", "password");
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
            Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
            for (Address address : in) {
                System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
            }

            Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
            BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
            System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
            System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
            System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());

       System.out.println("Activation Link:" + ((String) 
       bp.getContent()).startsWith("http"));

            String [] line =  new String[1];

            line [0] = mp.getContentType().toString();
            System.out.println("Activation Link:" + (mp.getBodyPart(0).getLineCount()));

            System.out.println("Activation Link:" +line[0]);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
 //WebDriver Stuffs
 public String activationUrl() {
//getting the url link and making it a global variable .... etc
    //Accessing the link 
 }  
    }
```

Comment: I agree with the sentiment that relying on the browser implementation of the email client is not good, which is why I was looking at a more API approach querying the mail server. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/cmendible/netDumbster or http://ndumbster.sourceforge.net/default.html. I've used one i forget which. This will host an smtp listener and allow you to make assertions against any email it receives. Its kind of awesome! The caveat is you need to be able to control where the server delivers mail in the environment you are testing.